# Replacing substrings with Strings not using replace()

Tags: java, indexof

The problem is: `mutation()` is passed two Strings and returns a String.  Every occurrence in the first String of `fzgh` is replaced with the second String.

```
mutation("Hello. I  want an fzgh.  Give me an fzgh now.", "IPhone 6")-> "Hello. I want an IPhone 6.  Give me an IPhone 6 now."
```

Here's my attempt:

```
public static String mutation(String s, String t){
    int f=s.indexOf("fzgh");
    String w="";
    if(f !=-1){
        w=w+s.substring(0,f)+t;
    }
    return w;  
}
```

I know there's `.replace()`, but we are not allowed to use it. We have to use `indexOf()`

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Hint: `f` will either always be -1 and hence not enter the loop... Or it ll never be -1 and loop indefinitely...

Comment: @JimN what do you mean?

Comment: If you are going to ask for help and state that your code doesn't work as you expect, then you need to be able to describe what you expect, and describe what you received instead.  You should also learn some basic debugging skills.

Comment: I expect it to return "Hello. I want an IPhone 6.  Give me an IPhone 6 now." Right now, I only have "Hello. I want an IPhone 6." As to the debugging skills, I've just started to learn coding so obviously I'm struggling, which is why I'm asking for help

Comment: Are you allowed to use Collections ?

Comment: @AritroSen No, I'm not

Comment: You have two fzgh. indexOf only returns the first occurrence.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder that's on purpose. I have to replace every time fzgh is in the String

Comment: This is obviously homework and you are not even close to valid solution. A bit more effort on your side would be appreciated.

Comment: My point is that your substring only contains up to the first fzgh. You need to look at what comes after the fzgh to see if there is another occurrence. You could, for example, have a while loop call this method as long as it contains fzgh, provided you can use contains()?

Comment: Do you always specifically know which String("fzgh" in this case) is to be replaced ? or is it any word which has more than 1 occurrence ?

Comment: @AritroSen it's specifically supposed to be "fzgh"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define mutation like this

```
public static String mutation(String s,String t){
 int f=s.indexOf("fzgh");
 int l =4;//length of "fzgh" 
 String w = s;
 while(f!=-1){
    w=w.substring(0,f)+t+w.substring(f+l,w.length());
    f=w.indexOf("fzgh");
 }
  return w;
}
```

This will remove all the "fzgh" from String s and will replace them with String t.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to initialize String t.

Comment: This code does not compile. `w` is declared twice. `t` is not declared.

Comment: Get rid of `String w = s`.
Change first line of while loop to `s=s.substring(0,f)+ w + s.substring(f+l,w.length());` and second line to `f = s.indexOf("fzgh");`

Comment: Sorry, ^^that should say `s.length()`. If you make these changes to your code, then it should work as you intended it to.

Comment: Actually, I meant to to use the same parameters as provided in the question, but made a few mistakes while typing the code here.

Comment: I have checked the code again. This will get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily solved if you can use `split` and `join` methods.

```
public static String mutation(String s, String t) {
    return String.join(t, s.split("fzgh"));
}
```

`split` will split the input string around `"fzgh"` and return an array of `String`, in this case, it will return `["Hello. I  want an ", ".  Give me an ", " now."]`. Now you can join the each element together with `"IPhone 6"` by using `join` method.

Notice that `join` is introduced in Java8.

But if you should only `indexOf` and `substring` to solve this problem, the code would be more complicated, but not so complex.

```
  public static String mutation(String s, String t) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int p = 0, q = 0;
    while ((q = s.indexOf("fzgh", p)) >= 0) {
      sb.append(s.substring(p, q));
      sb.append(t);
      p = q+4;
    }
    sb.append(s.substring(p));
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Comment: So much about my writing above :) Atleast I've learned a new thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda clumsy but there you go, i will edit meanwhile if u need explanation :)

*Edit: its not good enough yet, will try to fix it. This is kinda other way around, kinda different solution but not that good, will delete it if i fail to fix.

*Edit #2: Fixed

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

class Mutation
{
    public static String mutation(String s, String t){
        String toBeReplaced = "fzgh";
        int sizeOfThatString = toBeReplaced.length();
        String[] array = s.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String tempString= array[i];
            if(tempString.length()>sizeOfThatString) {
                if(tempString.contains(toBeReplaced)) {
                    String other = array[i].substring(sizeOfThatString);
                    array[i] = t+other;

                }
            }
            if(tempString.equals(toBeReplaced)) {
                array[i] = t;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(i!=array.length) {              
                sb.append(array[i]+" ");
            }
            else {
                sb.append(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arabic_Randomizer ar= new Arabic_Randomizer();
        System.out.println(ar.mutation("Hello. I  want an fzgh.  Give me an fzgh now.", "IPhone 6"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code 
    public class run {

```
       public static String mutation(String w,String s, String t){
           String toBeReplaced = w;
           int sizeOfThatString = toBeReplaced.length();
           String[] array = s.split(" ");
           for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
               String tempString= array[i];
               if(tempString.length()>sizeOfThatString) {
                   tempString = array[i].substring(0,sizeOfThatString);
                   System.out.println("TempString " +tempString);
               }
               if(tempString.equals(w)) {
                   array[i] = t;
               }
           }
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
               if(i!=array.length) {              
                   sb.append(array[i]+" ");
               }
               else {
                   sb.append(array[i]);
               }
           }
           return sb.toString();
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(mutation("fzgh","Hello. I  want an fzgh.  Give me an fzgh now.", "IPhone 6"));
       }
   }
```

out:

- TempString Hell
- TempString fzgh
- Hello. I  want an IPhone 6  Give me an IPhone 6 now.